# Incluir charset UTF-8 na conxão mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá, após reparar que meu código esta cheio de caracteres estranhos como ��� ???, tentei consertar mas descobri que preciso mudar o charset atravez da conexão mysqli, mas o problema é que não sei fazer isso!
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Aqui está meu código de conexão mysqli

***config.php***

```
<?php

//site specific configuration declartion
define( 'BASE_PATH', 'http://localhost/user_login/');
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '');
define( 'DB_NAME', 'login');

function __autoload($class)
{
    $parts = explode('_', $class);
    $path = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$parts);
    require_once $path . '.php';
}

?>
```

***DBclass***

```
<?php

    class Cl_DBclass
    {
    /**
     * @var $con vai realizar conexão com o banco
     */
    public $con;

    /**
     * Isto irá criar uma conexão de banco de dados
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if( mysqli_connect_error()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    }
?>
```

Desde já Obrigado!

Comment: Qual é o encode do banco e da sua página?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depois de fazer a conexão com o banco, chame [set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php), para mudar o charset. Use [character_set_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.character-set-name.php) para saber o charset atual.

```
$this->con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$this->con->set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: Este também não resolveu :-(  ������

Answer (score 6):

Uso dessa forma com mysql:

Você pode alterar o seu construtor para:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_error()) { // < evite IF sem chaves
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else {
        mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        mysqli_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
        mysqli_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
        mysqli_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
    }
}
```

Retorna todas as consultas sem problemas na codificação.

Comment: mysql**i** != mysql_*

Comment: @rray  Sei que é diferente, por isso disse que uso com o mysql. Nunca usei com mysqli pra saber se funciona. Ele pode testar.

Comment: O problema é que mysql_* é uma API obsoleta, não recebe atualizações desde ...

Comment: Coloquei este código mas continuam os ���.

Comment: Obrigado. Meu problema foi resolvido, mas observo que o mysqli_query() recebe dois, parametros, sendo o primeiro a conexão!

Answer (score 4):

Na minha conexão, eu coloco o charset abaixo fora do php:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Dentro do php eu coloco assim:

```
$con->set_charset("utf8");
```

As minhas páginas **html** com **"charset utf-8"** e no banco de dados coloco **collate "utf8_general_ci"**. Pronto, tá resolvido o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Problema Resolvido!
A pricipio, as soluções aqui dadas não estavam funcionando porque eu havia incluido este codigo em uma tentativa anterior de concertar:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
```

Então ultilizei uma das soluções dadas, (ambas funcionam) o exclui e troquei o valor da `meta tag charset` de `utf-8` para `iso-8859-1` ! Obrigado a todos!