# Erro de Charset UTF-8 ao retornar do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, codificação-de-caracteres, mariadb

O meu sistema está com erro de charset, porém são apenas com os dados retornados do banco de dados. O meu charset no HTML está certo, o do banco de dados também está certo, e no `php.ini` também está certo.

Como consigo resolver o problema? Os caracteres especiais estão retornando `?`.

Comment: você esta usando PDO ?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77491/incluir-charset-utf-8-na-conx%C3%A3o-mysqli/77494#77494

Comment: Não da pra dizer que o problema é apenas com o mysql ou mariadb, estas dicas devem lhe ajudar com o php, html e o banco: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defina o charset desejado em tempo de execução.

Se estiver usando PDO, faça:

```
$pdo->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Em `Mysqli`:

```
mysqli_query($mysql, 'SET NAMES utf8')
```